# Network connection check always return false for some Android devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-connectivitymanager

I am using this methods for check network connection but some users getting "no internet connection" error even they have connected to internet. Users reviewed with; **Huawei Mate 10 Lite, LGE V20, Asus Zenfone, Samsung Galaxy A8**

My methods:

```
private fun isConnectionOn(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as
                ConnectivityManager

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        postAndroidMInternetCheck(connectivityManager)
    } else {
        preAndroidMInternetCheck(connectivityManager)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun postAndroidMInternetCheck(
    connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
): Boolean {
    val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    val connection =
        connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)

    return connection != null && (
            connection.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                    connection.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
}

private fun preAndroidMInternetCheck(
    connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
): Boolean {
    val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        return (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI ||
                activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: did you findout the reason of this issue? Does the answer is helped? I have the same problem on some devices.

Answer (score 2):

Validating that you are connected to Wi-Fi or Cellular won't accurately tell you if you have internet connectivity. What if you drive through a tunnel with cellular? What if you connect to a captive portal over Wi-fi to which you don't have access to? You'll still return true in both of these cases even though you don't have internet connectivity. These are just a couple examples but point being, you shouldn't use transport to validate connectivity.

The two capabilities that you should use to validate connectivity would be [NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) and [NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED).

> NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET Added in API level 21
>
> public static final int NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET Indicates that this
> network should be able to reach the internet.
>
> NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED Added in API level 23
>
> public static final int NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED Indicates that
> connectivity on this network was successfully validated. For example,
> for a network with NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it means that Internet
> connectivity was successfully detected.

Therefore for Android >= M you could update your code like so:

```
return connection != null && (
            connection.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                    connection.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED))
```

For Android < M you should use either (based off of your use-case) [NetworkInfo#isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#isConnected()) or [NetworkInfo#isConnectedOrConnecting()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#isConnectedOrConnecting()).

> public boolean isConnected ()
>
> Indicates whether network connectivity exists and it is possible to
> establish connections and pass data.
>
> Always call this before attempting to perform data transactions.

Therefore for Android < M you could update your code like so:

```
if (activeNetwork != null) {
    return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: I will try these, thank you. If errors disappears on analytics, i will mark your answer as accepted, thanks again.

Comment: Hi @furkanbzkurt, did this error end up disappearing? Thanks.